# encrypt large file with c# and decrypt with android java code

Tags: c#, android, encryption, large-files

i have used the code sample in the following link:

http://zenu.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/aes-128bit-cross-platform-java-and-c-encryption-compatibility/

to encrypt a file in c# and decrypt it in android and it works great; but when i tried to do the same with a large file i got OutOfMemory exception, i found that the bug is in the cypher.dofinal method and i changed it to use cypher.update method and read the file in parts and the code worked but some peaces of the text was decrypted successfully and some was not, i did a lot of research but it seems i am missing somthing here, any help will be appreciated , thx in advance.

Comment: The linked code is defect and will not work under certain conditions (especially get getkeyBytes method). I strongly recommend not to use this method!!! Use a proper key derivation function instead like PBKDF2.

Comment: hi, thx for ur reply, but i dont have a problem with the key since i have already fixed this issue.